# Entity Framework Core 5 using let keywords not supported?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate our code from EF6 into EF Core 5 and have stuck getting some errors.
The code that i'm using (part of it) is:

```
var usersQuery = (
    from u in RepositoryContext.Users//.AsExpandable()
    from n in RepositoryContext.NewsLetters.Where(x => x.IsSubscriber && u.Email.ToLower() == x.EmailAddress.ToLower())
    
    let oldStyleResearches = (from ac in RepositoryContext.AssessmentCodes
                              join a in RepositoryContext.Assessments on ac.AssessmentKey equals a.AssessmentKey
                              join r in RepositoryContext.Research on a.AssessmentKey equals r.AssessmentKey
                              where ac.UserID == u.Id && a.CompletedDate != null
                              orderby a.CompletedDate descending
                              select new
                              {
                                  Date = a.CompletedDate.Value,
                                  Gender = r.Gender,
    
                              })
    let newStyleResearches = (from ac in RepositoryContext.AssessmentCodes
                              join a in RepositoryContext.Assessments on ac.AssessmentKey equals a.AssessmentKey
                              join rr in RepositoryContext.ResearchResponses on a.AssessmentKey equals rr.AssessmentKey
                              where ac.UserID == u.Id && a.CompletedDate != null
                              orderby rr.CreatedOn descending
                              select new 
                              {
                                  Date = rr.CreatedOn,
                                  //I had to do some mappings like that as questions do not have common type shared between surveys...
                                  Gender = rr.SurveyId == 1 ? RepositoryContext.ResearchAnswers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResponseId == rr.ID && x.QuestionId == 3).Value :
                                           rr.SurveyId == 2 ? RepositoryContext.ResearchAnswers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResponseId == rr.ID && x.QuestionId == 17).Value : string.Empty,
                              })
    let researches = oldStyleResearches.Union(newStyleResearches).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    
    let firstNonNullWithGender = researches.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Gender))
    
    select new GetMailChimpUserDatabaseResult
    {
        Id = null,
    
        FirstName = string.Empty,
        LastName = string.Empty,
        Email = n.EmailAddress,
        Gender = firstNonNullWithGender != null ? firstNonNullWithGender.Gender : string.Empty,
    });

var result = usersQuery.ToList();
```

this generates error like:

> The query contains a projection '<>h__TransparentIdentifier2 =>
> <>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.oldStyleResearches
> .Union(<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.newStyleResearches)
> .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)' of type 'IOrderedQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType108<DateTime, string>>'.
> Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable' type
> such as 'List'. Consider using 'ToList' or some other mechanism to
> convert the 'IQueryable' or 'IOrderedEnumerable' into an
> 'IEnumerable'.

I think in our situation EF core does not like the use of let keywords, we have a lot of code like the one above where we used to use let in EF6 and that did great for reusability and readability of statements in "current" query. Is this pattern totally not supported in EF core or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like they don't like `IQueryable` projections (`Select` - this what `let` is behind the scenes).  Have no idea why they refer to *final projection*, these variables (selects) are not used in the final projection which is `new GetMailChimpUserDatabaseResult { ...}`, sounds like EFC bug to me.

Comment: also I tried adding ToList() which error is suggesting (makes no sense to me). Added this after oldStyleResearches, newStyleResearches  and thier union but this results in just another error saying :
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Best to ask on their GitHub repo - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue when the code is migrated from EF Core 3.X to EF Core 5.X.
Which is related to the changes that have been made in client and server evaluation in entity framework.
Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) for more information.

A workaround to fix this issue is to use explicit client evaluation by calling methods like AsEnumerable or ToList (AsAsyncEnumerable or ToListAsync for async) at the end of the subquery defined in the "let".
[Explicit client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation)

Comment: How is this a "workaround"? By forcing explicit client evaluation, you are breaking any scenario where you are dealing with "`Big Data`" transactions having many thousands of values that need to be evaluated for the subsequent query.